# Push Notifications with Ionic 3 and Amazon Pinpoint

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, ionic-framework, apple-push-notifications, aws-pinpoint

I am trying to setup up push notifications in my Ionic 3 app.

I am using the AWS pinpoint service to build campaigns and push messages to devices.  Specifically iOS devices.

I have the backend setup and I can track devices using Pinpoint analytics console.

I have added the push plugin to my Iconic app, and I am able to request permission to receive push notifications.  I have signed my app with a cert and also setup AWS with a cert, so as far as I know all the pieces are in place on the backend.

I can debug the Ionic app and grab the device token, e.g.

```
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => {
    console.debug("Device Token:", registration.registrationId);
});
```

I can use this token in the AWS Pinpoint console, Direct messaging to send and successfully receive a APNS message on the test device.

My question is, how do I register the token with AWS for use in campaigns?

Furthermore my Pinpoint console shows no targetable endpoints , which is what I believe I need to setup from my Ionic app, but I can't find any examples anywhere.

All help greatly received....

Lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Analytics.updateEndpoint request to add your device to pinpoint when not using the Amplify Push Notifications module (non-react-native). Update the `Address` property with that device token:

```
const config = {
       Address: token,
       OptOut: 'NONE'
 };
 Analytics.updateEndpoint(config).then((data) => {
        console.log('update endpoint success, setting token into cache');
  }).catch(e => {
        console log('update endpoint failed', e);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks Michael!!   I had worked out the token had to go into the address for the config.  But not the OptOut property!!!  This solved my problem !  So thanks a million for that! Why don't AWS mention OptOut in any of the examples ????!!  I burnt probably a month on and off trying to solve this issue !!!  I found this great api reference link, which explains all the params [link]https://docs.aws.amazon.com/pinpoint/latest/apireference/rest-api-endpoint.html#rest-api-endpoint-schemas